# Python argparse subparser valid usage?

Tags: python, argparse, subparsers

I am planing to write a command using the argparse library, this is my command structure:

```
$ python cvs.py -d my_adress local diff -r xyz -N -d details
```

Here, the local has multiple command grouped to it such as local commit, local add etc.
E.g. [-d my_address] is parsed in main and all switches after local diff are parsed together by a function executed for local diff.

Similarly, there is another command group parallel to local; say global.

The switch -d is not mixed with -r. So, the parser parsing -r doesn't know about -d and vice versa.

Is it possible to implement this using argparse? If yes, can somebody suggest me a rough algorithm to do this.
If no, What are other possible way to do this in python?
Thanks.

Comment: Your description is not clear.  What do you mean by 'local has multiple command[s] inside it'?  Flagged arguments like `-d` are parsed independently, and can occur in any order.  Remember, `argparse` parses your input, but does not execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `nargs` parameter, namely the `'*'` option.
It won't do a subparse (I do not think that argparse can to that at all), but it will at least group your options so you'll get `-d` and `-r` returned as separate options.
`-N` won't be a known option. I don't know whether argparse would consider it an error (which you don't want), or just another parameter of `-r`.

Your approach might fail. CVS subcommands can have all sorts of one-letter options like `-d`, `-r`, etc. (it's [a long list](https://www-e815.fnal.gov/webspace/cvs/commands.html)). You'll find yourself constantly making hard choices of whether you want to support a specific CVS option as a subcommand or rather use the letter for your `cvs.py` option.

You could introduce some markup to separate CVS subcommands, i.e. `python cvs.py -d my_adress local diff § -r xyz -N`. However, that's not a real improvement over `cvs -d my_adress local diff; cvs -r xyz -N` anymore.